# Retrieve All Posts and the user data data in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

The Parent Model - **User**

```
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

The Child Model- **Post**

```
public function user_posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,"id");
}
```

Now in the Route, I was trying to print- *Every post and the name of the admin -*

```
Route::get("/admin/posts",function() {

    $posts = Post::all();

    foreach($posts as $post) {

        $userId = $post->id;

        $userName = Post::findOrFail($userId)->user_posts->name;

        echo "<pre>
                Title - $post->title 
                 Content - $post->content
                 Author - <mark>$userName</mark>
            </pre>";

    }
});
```

By running this code it only prints only the first post of the admins and shows an error ***Trying to get property 'name' of non-object***

**Pulling out by single post id it prints the user data it works fine**

```
Route::get("/admin_data_by/postsId",function() {
        $postId = 1;
        $userName = Post::findOrFail($postId)->user_posts->name;
        echo "<pre>
                 Author - <mark>$userName</mark>
            </pre>";
});
```

> Migrations- **User**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Migration- **Post**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer("user_id")->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->string("title");
        $table->text("content");
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: your relationship foreign key is wrong..have you read the laravel doc??

Comment: please provide your migrations too

Comment: You Also try to get users with the Post model. You really need to read the docs. You should also use controllers/views instead of putting everything in the route.

Comment: `$userId = $post->id;` ?? That sounds wrong

Answer (score 0):

just change your route method to the following and and everything will work for you

```
$postId = 1;
$userName = Post::firstOrFail('id', $postId)->user_posts->name;
echo "<pre>
Author - <mark>$userName</mark>
</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you first get object and show parameters in object

please get data with below code

```
$user = Post::findOrFail($userId);
$post = $user->user_posts;
echo "<pre>
                Title - $post->title 
                 Content - $post->content
                 Author - <mark>$post->name</mark>
            </pre>";
```